# What is general term of the sequence : $1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 32, 32 ...$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence as follows:

$$1, 2, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 32, 32 ...$$

What will be the closed form of the above sequence for the nth term?

I clearly see the pattern of $2^x$ getting repeated $2^{x-1}$ times. But I am getting confused in finding the closed form of this sequence.

EDIT:

Thanks @Arthur for providing the closed form. Now to extend the questiona bit further, **what would be the sum upto nth term given the closed form?**.

Looking at the closed form, it seems like that the sum would be of the order of $N^2$, but not able to find the exact value. I would like to see how much difference would it make because of the "ceiling" function.

Comment: I think you went wrong while writing the sequence here. Kindly reconsider it.

Comment: Then $2=2^1$ should repeated $2^0=1$-times, not $2$-times.

Comment: And 1 also does not follow the pattern you wrote. Have you wrote it incorrect by mistake or is this sequence correct?

Comment: My bad. Sorry. Updated the sequence now. 2 should be repeated only once.

Comment: I do not understand very well to the notion of "closed-form". Can that be also a recursive expression?

Comment: @TStancek Are you asking if the OP would accept a recursive expression as his solution? Or are you asking if "closed-form" is equivalent to "recursive"? I can answer the second one by saying a "closed-form" would be different from "recursive" in that a "closed-form" expression would not require calculating any of the previous entries in the sequence and instead directly find the desired term.

Comment: @BrianJ Just wanted to know whether $a_0=1$ with $a_{2n}=2a_n$ for $n\neq 0$ and $a_{2n+1}=2a_n$ is also a closed form.

Comment: @TStancek My understanding is that that would not be closed form, because to calculate when $a_{10}$, you'd need to calculate $a_5$, $a_4$, $a_2$, and $a_1$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C4%2C4%2C8%2C8%2C8%2C8%2C16%2C16%2C16%2C16%2C16%2C16%2C16%2C16%2C32%2C32&language=english&go=Search leads immediately to a closed formula for your sequence.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If we start indexing at $n = 1$, we get $$a_n = 2^{\lceil \log_2 n\rceil}$$where $\lceil - \rceil$ is the ceiling function.

Comment: Thanks Arthur for your answer. Just curious to know, what would be the sum upto nth term of it.

Answer (score 1):

If we start indexing at $n=1$, the sum I believe is this:

$$s_n=(n-2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor})\cdot a_n+2\cdot\frac{4^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}-1}{3}+1$$